# How to pass 'next' parameter to Django Auth logout_then_login view?

Tags: python, django

I am using Django 1.6, django.contrib.auth.views.  I am using the login and logout url definitions below. Right now, when a user clicks my logout link, the 'logout_then_login' view gets triggered like it should, but when the user logs back in, the 'next' parameter is undefined and the page is forwarded to the default 'accounts/profile' path.  What I would rather have happen is the logout_then_login view forward a 'next' value to the login view.

For example, the user is on page /foo/bar when they click logout.  I would like them to be sent to the login screen with '/foo/bar' set as the next paramter, so when they login right away again, they are back on the same page they were at.  I want it to be dynamic, based on the request.path when the logout link is clicked. I am aware of the static solution of overriding the default value for next when it is undefined.

Current urls.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout_then_login


urlpatterns = patterns('base.views',
    url(r'^accounts/login/$',  login, name='login'),
    url(r'^accounts/logout/$', logout_then_login, name='logout'),
)
```

I have tried using the extra_context argument for logout_then_login, but not even sure how it should look using a named url in a template:

```
<a href="{% url 'logout' extra_context={'next': request.path } %}">Log Out</a>
```

Am I on the right track - or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so this turned out to be way easy. I was over thinking it when I was trying to cram the next parameter into the url template tag.

I simply needed to tack on the next parameter after the url template tag:

```
<a href="{% url 'logout' %}?next={{request.path}}"> Log Out</a>
```